# MySQL - self join optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization, join

I have a table of phone events by HomeId. Each row has an EventId (on hook, off hook, ring, DTMF, etc), TimeStamp, Sequence (auto increment) and HomeId. Im working on a query to find specific types of occurrences(IE inbound or outbound calls) and duration.

I had planned on doing this using a multiple self-join on this table to pick out the sequences of events that usually indicate one type of occurrence or the other. EG inbound calls would be  a period of inactivity followed by no DTMF, then ringing and caller id (possibly) then an off hook. I would find the next on-hook and thus have the duration.

My table is indexed by HomeId, EventId and Sequence and has ~60K records. When I do an 'explain' of my query it shows indexing and 75, 75, 1, 1, 748 for the row counts. Seems pretty doable. But when I run the query its taking more than 10 minutes (at which point the MySQL query browser times out).

Query for outbound calls:

```
select pe0.HomeId, pe1.Stamp, pe1.mSec, timediff( pe4.Stamp, pe0.Stamp ) from Phone_Events pe0 
join Phone_Events pe1 on pe0.HomeId = pe1.HomeId and pe1.Sequence = pe0.Sequence - 1 and abs(timediff( pe0.Stamp, pe1.Stamp )) > 10
join Phone_Events pe2 on pe0.HomeId = pe2.HomeId and pe2.Sequence = pe0.Sequence + 1 and pe2.EventId = 22
join Phone_Events pe4 on pe4.HomeId = pe0.HomeId and pe4.EventId = 30 and pe4.Stamp > pe0.Stamp
where pe0.eventId = 12 and pe0.HomeId = 111
AND
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Phone_Events pe3
               WHERE pe3.HomeId = pe0.HomeId
               AND pe3.EventId not in( 13, 22 ) 
               AND pe3.Stamp > pe0.Stamp and pe3.Stamp < pe4.Stamp );
```

Is there something specific to self joining that makes this slow? Is there a better way to optimize this? The killer seems to be the 'not exists' portion - this part is there to make sure there are no events between the last 'on hook' and the current 'off hook'.

EDIT: EventId's as follows:

```
'1', 'device connection'  
'2', 'device disconnection'  
'3', 'device alarm'
'11', 'ring start'
'12', 'off hook'
'13', 'hang up(other end)'
'15', 'missed call'
'21', 'caller id'
'22', 'dtmf'
'24', 'device error'
'30', 'on hook'
'31', 'ring stop'
```

Comment: looks like an index on Stamp will be helpful

Comment: Primary key is (Sequence, Home). There are also indexes on (Sequence, Home), EventId and HomeId.

Comment: abs(timediff( pe0.Stamp, pe1.Stamp )) <-- this can't be good for performance.

Comment: There are so my things that could kill us here. How many records in Phone_Events per HomeId? Can we see the schema, including indexes, for the relevant tables and columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete rewrite based on new information.  How I approached this was to start with an inner-most query to get all records we care about based exclusively on HomeID = 111 and make sure they came back pre-sorted by the sequence ID (have index on HomeID, Sequence).  As we all know, a phone call starts by picking up the phone -- eventID = 12, getting dial tone -- eventid = 22, dialing out, and someone answering, until the phone is back on the hook -- eventid = 30).  If its a hangup (eventid=13), we want to ignore it.

I don't know why you are looking at the sequence # PRIOR to the current call, don't know if it really has any bearing.  It looks like you are just trying to get completed calls and how long the duration.  That said, I would remove the portion of the LEFT JOIN Phone_Event and the corresponding WHERE clause.  It may have been there while you were just trying to figure this out.

Anyhow, back to the logic.  The inner most guarantees the call sequences in order.  You won't have two calls simultaneous.  So by getting them in order first, I then join to the SQLVars (which creates inline variable @NextCall for the query).  The purpose for this is to identify every time a new call is about to begin (EventID = 12).  If so, take whatever the sequence number is, and save it.  This will remain the same until the next call, so all the other "event IDs" will have the same "starting sequence ID".  In addition, I'm looking for the other events... an event = 22 based on the starting sequence +1 and setting it as a flag.  Then, the max time based on the start of the call (only set when eventid = 12), and end of the call (eventid = 30), and finally a flag based on your check for a hang up (eventid = 13) ie: don't consider the call if it was a hangup and no connection through.

By doing a group by, I've in essence, rolled-up each call to its own line... grouped by the home ID, and the sequence number used to initiate the actual phone call.  Once THAT is done, I can then query the data and compute the call duration since the start/end time are on the same row, no self-self-self joins involved.

Finally, the where clause... Kick out any phone calls that HAD a HANG UP.  Again, I don't know if you still need the element of what the starting call's time was of the last ending event.

```
SELECT
      PreGroupedCalls.*,
      timediff( PreGroupedCalls.CallEndTime, PreGroupedCalls.CallStartTime ) CallDuration 
   from
      ( SELECT
              Calls.HomeID,
              @NextCall := @NextCall + if( Calls.EventID = 12, Calls.Sequence, @NextCall ) as NextNewCall,
              MAX( if( Calls.EventID = 12, Calls.Stamp, 0 )) as CallStartTime,
              MAX( if( Calls.EventID = 30, Calls.Stamp, 0 )) as CallEndTime,
              MAX( if( Calls.EventID = 22 and Calls.Sequence = @NewCallFirstSeq +1, 1, 0 )) as HadDTMFEntry,
              MAX( if( Calls.EventID = 13 and Calls.Sequence = @NewCallFirstSeq +1, 1, 0 )) as WasAHangUp
           from 
              ( select pe.HomeId, 
                       pe.Sequence,
                       pe.EventID,
                       pe.Stamp
                   from
                      Phone_Events pe
                   where 
                      pe.HomeID = 111
                   order by
                      pe.Sequence ) Calls,
              ( select @NextCall := 0 ) SQLVars
           group by
              Calls.HomeID,
              NextNewCall ) PreGroupedCalls

         LEFT JOIN Phone_Event PriorCallEvent
            ON PreGroupCalls.NextNewCall = PriorCallEvent.Sequence -1 
   where
         PreGroupedCalls.WasHangUp = 0
      AND ( PriorCallEvent.Sequence IS NULL
         OR abs(timediff( PriorCallEvent.Stamp, PreGroupedCalls.CallStartTime )) > 10 )
```

**COMMENT FROM FEEDBACK / ERROR reported**

To try and fix the DOUBLE error, you obviously will need to make a slight change in the SQLVars select.. try the following

( select @NextCall := CAST( 0 as INT ) ) SQLVars

Now, what the IF() is doing... Lets take a look.

@NextCall + if(Calls.EventID = 12,Calls.Sequence, @NextCall)

means take a look at the Event ID.  If it is a 12 (ie: off-hook), grab whatever the sequence number is for that entry.  This will become the new "Starting Sequence" of another call.  If not, just keep whatever the last value set was, as its a continuation of a call in progress.  Now, lets look at some simulated data to help better illustrate all the columns

```
Original data                    Values that will ultimately be built into...
HomeID Sequence EventID Stamp    @NextCall
111    1        12      8:00:00    1  beginning of a new call
111    2        22      8:00:01    1  not a new "12" event, keep last value
111    3        30      8:05:00    1  call ended, phone back on hook
111    4        12      8:09:00    4  new call, use the sequence of THIS entry
111    5        22      8:09:01    4  same call
111    6        13      8:09:15    4  same call, but a hang up
111    7        30      8:09:16    4  same call, phone back on hook
111    8        12      8:15:30    8  new call, get sequence ID
111    9        22      8:15:31    8  same call...
111   10        30      8:37:15    8  same call ending...

Now, the query SHOULD create something like this
HomeID   NextNewCall   CallStartTime  CallEndTime   HadDTMFEntry  WasAHangUp
111      1             8:00:00        8:05:00       1             0
111      4             8:09:00        8:09:16       1             1
111      8             8:15:30        8:37:15       1             0
```

As you can see, the @NextCall keeps all the sequential entries for a given call "Grouped" together so you don't have to just use greater than span information or less than... It is always going to follow a certain path of "events", so whatever is the one that started the call is the basis for the rest of the events until the next call is started, then THAT sequence is grabbed for THAT group call.

Yup, its a lot to grasp.. but hopefully now more digestible for you :)

Comment: Hmm.. I added the new index and ran your version. Still hitting the 10min timeout. The server in question is an 8cpu, 16Gb RAM RHEL machine with no other load on it (at the moment). Seems like this should be much faster.

Comment: @ethrbunny, let me ask you this... The "HomeID" is this auto-assigned too?  Is it the phone extension the call is originating?  The timestamp range... Is there a timeframe limit your are expecting?  Can you post SOME of the sample data with your query?

Comment: @ethrbunny, Can you please list the different Event IDs, and their corresponding codes... I have an idea that might work... In addition, you have a timestamp, but querying the entire file... Any consideration to LIMIT a given time period... such as for a day, week, month?

Comment: Edited to include EventId range. HomeId is assigned from where the phone sensor is installed. No limit on time stamp values though the study is less than a year old.

Comment: The `NOT IN` clause is still a killer here. It might be better to do `pe3.EventID <> 13 AND pe3.EventID <> 22`, assuming there's an index on EventID.

Comment: @ethrbunny, complete rewrite, check it out, see if it makes sense.

Comment: @MarcusAdams, completely rewrote per extra info provided to analyze a single call at a time sequentially per HomeID.

Comment: Wow. This is huge. Trying to digest it. --> one thing: am getting error at 'DOUBLE value is out of range in '((@NextCall) + if((`Calls`.`EventID` = 12),`Calls`.`Sequence`,(@NextCall)))' <-- what are you trying to do here?

Comment: @ethrbunny, so it apparently worked out and hope performance is descent... however, my concern about the extra left join for the previous call... was that still necessary, or did you actually get to  remove it once you saw what/how things were happening otherwise.