# Self join tree MYSQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, tree, self-join

Here is my categories table

```
category_id | parent_id
 ____________________________
       27   |       25
       28   |       27
       29   |       25
       26   |       28
       25   |        0
       30   |        0
       31   |       26
    ..........
    ..........
```

I want to show the records like this.

```
   category_id  | parent_id
 ____________________________
    25  |        0     
    27  |       25
    28  |       27
    26  |       28
    31  |       26
    29  |       25
    30  |        0

    ..........
    ..........
```

I have seen lots of post on it but I find nothing for me.
Please let me know query for my categories table. Thanks.
Here are some links that i have looked already.
1:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025250/mysql-self-join-optimization)
2: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28341981/php-traverse-category-subcategory-tree-array-into-a-custom-2d-array)

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: what's your logic to get data in such a way

Comment: `27` and `29` have the same `parent_id 25`, why `29` is after `31`?

Comment: It looks like you only want to order the result in a different order? There is no difference in the two results above except the order? But I cant figure out what order that is...? Are there more columns in the table?

Comment: What does "like this" mean? You need to explain.

Comment: @Forward because this 27 and 29 is top most child of 25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(category_id INT NOT NULL
,parent_id INT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(27,25),
(28,27),
(29,25),
(26,28),
(25,NULL),
(30,NULL),
(31,26);

SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
  FROM my_table t1
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table t2 
    ON t2.parent_id = t1.category_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table t3 
    ON t3.parent_id = t2.category_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table t4 
    ON t4.parent_id = t3.category_id
 ORDER
    BY t4.parent_id DESC 
     , t3.parent_id DESC
     , t2.parent_id DESC
     , t1.parent_id DESC;

+-------------+-----------+
| category_id | parent_id |
+-------------+-----------+
|          25 |      NULL |
|          27 |        25 |
|          28 |        27 |
|          26 |        28 |
|          31 |        26 |
|          29 |        25 |
|          30 |      NULL |
+-------------+-----------+
```

or something like that.

Because MySQL does not yet have native support for recursion<sup>†</sup>, this becomes a bit of mouthful, hence the popularity of alternative models, e.g. *nested set*...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(category_id INT NOT NULL
,lft INT NOT NULL
,rgt INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(0,1,16),
(25,2,13),
(27,3,10),
(28,4,9),
(26,5,8),
(31,6,7),
(29,11,12),
(30,14,15);

SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY lft;
+-------------+-----+-----+
| category_id | lft | rgt |
+-------------+-----+-----+
|           0 |   1 |  16 |
|          25 |   2 |  13 |
|          27 |   3 |  10 |
|          28 |   4 |   9 |
|          26 |   5 |   8 |
|          31 |   6 |   7 |
|          29 |  11 |  12 |
|          30 |  14 |  15 |
+-------------+-----+-----+
```

<sup>†</sup> MySQL 8.0 will add support for [recursive CTE syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html).

Comment: @BillKarwin - Oh man, now I've got to go learn a whole load of new stuff!